# FQL Stream Facebook Application publish_stream

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql

I want to create/show an activity stream of everything that has been published/commented on behalf of my application. My question is, do I need to "farm" any "post" id's or am I able to call upon everything posted into the stream via my application from it's id in a FQL statement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not retrieve application stream, despite what the doc says.

Give a look at: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13662

Answer (score 0):

Actually in many cases you can use app_ID as the filter_key.  This doesn't work for some apps reliably though and I don't know why...

```
select post_id, source_id, app_id, attachment, created_time, action_links
from stream
where filter_key in ('app_2339854854')
```